# How to separate a string with a sign in the middle

Tags: fortran

I am working on a code that needs to get the two variables of a binomial expression. I want to know if there's a way to separate a string with a sign in the middle into two substrings.

```
e.g. (x+y)^3 to var1=x and var2=y or (qwerty-asdf)^12 to var1=qwerty and var2=asdf
```

I have tried doing this:

```
character(100) :: str, var
var=' ' 
do i=1,len(str)
    if (((str(i:i) == "+") .or. (str(i:i) == "-")) .or. &
    ((str(i:i) >= "a") .and. (str(i:i) <= "z"))) &
    var=trim(var)//trim(str(i:i))   
end do
```

But the only characters that get removed are the parenthesis and the power.

Another way that I'm looking at my problem is that if I know what the string length where the signs are then I can do this:

```
character(100) :: str, var
    var=' ' 
    do i=1,len(the_unknown_string_length)
        if ((str(i:i) >= "a") .and. (str(i:i) <= "z")) &
        var=trim(var)//trim(str(i:i))   
    end do
```

Although, I also don't know how I could get the specific string length where the signs appear.

Comment: The [index](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/INDEX-intrinsic.html) intrinsic will probably help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't mess about with loops - I'd use the available intrinsic functions. Something like

```
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ cat binom.f90
Program binom

  Implicit None

  Character( Len = 100 ) :: expression

  Character( Len = : ), Allocatable :: var1, var2

  Write( *, '( a )' ) 'Expression?'
  Read ( *, '( a )' ) expression

  Call split_it( expression, var1, var2 )

  If( Len( var1 ) /= 0 .And. Len( var2 ) /= 0 ) Then
     Write( *, '( a, a, t20, i0 )' ) 'Var1 = ', var1, Len( var1 )
     Write( *, '( a, a, t20, i0 )' ) 'Var2 = ', var2, Len( var2 )
  Else
     Write( *, * ) 'No + or - in the string'
  End If

Contains

  Subroutine split_it( expression, var1, var2 )

    Implicit None

    Character( Len = * ),              Intent( In    ) :: expression
    Character( Len = : ), Allocatable, Intent(   Out ) :: var1
    Character( Len = : ), Allocatable, Intent(   Out ) :: var2

    Integer :: split_pos
    Integer :: paren_pos

    split_pos = Scan( expression, '+-' )

    If( split_pos /= 0 ) Then

       var1 = Trim( Adjustl( expression( :split_pos - 1 ) ) )
       paren_pos = Scan( var1, '(' )
       var1 = Trim( Adjustl( var1( paren_pos + 1: ) ) )

       var2 = Trim( Adjustl( expression( split_pos + 1: ) ) )
       paren_pos = Scan( var2, ')' )
       var2 = Trim( Adjustl( var2( :paren_pos - 1 ) ) )

    Else

       Allocate( Character( Len = 0 ) :: var1 )
       Allocate( Character( Len = 0 ) :: var2 )

    End If

  End Subroutine split_it
  
End Program binom
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ gfortran -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -std=f2008 -g binom.f90 
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
Expression?
(x+y)^3
Var1 = x           1
Var2 = y           1
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
Expression?
(qwerty-asdf)^12
Var1 = qwerty      6
Var2 = asdf        4
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
Expression?
( aag + fg ) ^98
Var1 = aag         3
Var2 = fg          2
ijb@ijb-Latitude-5410:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
Expression?
wibble
 No + or - in the string
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! We haven't reached all the intrinsic functions yet in our lectures so I didn't think about using it. Thanks again.